# Symfony console outputs "i" and commands do not work in Netbeans

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I recently updated my composer.phar file to upgrade all of my dependencies, and after that the , the Symfony2 commands in Netbeans no longer works.  When I select Run command, an error message says:

```
<There is no command available (perhaps error?)>
```

In the output window, it looks like the comand list is being generated, except for one problem

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/home/web/Project/app/console" "--ansi" "list" "--xml"
i<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <symfony name="Symfony" version="2.5.0 - app/dev/debug">
  <commands>
```

Notice that the second line begins with "i".  I think this is the cause of the problem and am not sure how to get rid of it.  When I open up a console window, all of the commands work, but each command has the output begin with an i.

I have an older test project, and the commands still work in that so this error must have happened when I updated composer.

I just realized this is a bigger issue.  The i is outputted on all pages so none of the pages appear correctly anymore since it begins with i instead of the  tag.

Anyone come across this before or know how to prevent symfony from generating the i?

Comment: I doubt Symfony is generating an 'i' randomly. If you use versioning (such as SVN or GIT) try identifying what else has changed in your project. Could be a typo in one of your php files.

Comment: I know, this is a very strange error.  I created a new symfony2 project from scratch and imported all of the bundles I created to see if any one of them broke the new project.  After incorporating every bundle and using the exact same config, parameters, and service files...the new project worked fine but the old one still outputs i.  It would be nice to know how this happened but at least I have a working project now.